# heroku error with rails app: Error with build stream, polling for results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

For some reason, when I push a rails app to heroku, I am getting the following error:

```
Error with build stream, polling for results..................
```

It never actually return errors after that.  The dots keep on increasing.  The only line of code I've changed since the last commit was html in a view file.  I added:

```
<p>For more info, please contact us at info@mysite.com</p>
```

I've used heroku before and never received this error.  how do i fix it?

Comment: When I've gotten this message before it has eventually resolved itself if I just let it sit for a long time.

Comment: Right now am getting this error message. any fixes for this ? @Andrew

Comment: @martin in this case, see the heroku system status. At the moment there's a service outage.

Comment: Yes executed command "heroku status"  from my console & it shows that currently engineers are looking into issue over heroku, hence down. :)

Comment: this issue started occurring BEFORE heroku reported incidents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. According to the site they're aware of the problem and are working on it.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/711#update-2433